# How to add active class/state for li element in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm struggling with one issue all day long... I have list of books and after click user can see details of each books. I want to add `background-color` when element `li` is clicked (something like an `active` class). I use Redux and React and have no idea what is the best approach to create this feature. Please, give me some hints because I'm getting discouraged to React environment...

book-list.js

```
class BookList extends Component {
    renderList(){
        return this.props.books.map((book) => {
            return (
                <li key={book.title} 
                    className="list-group-item" 
                    onClick={() => this.props.selectBook(book)}>
                    {book.title}
                </li>
            )
        })
    }

render () {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3 className="m-t-2 m-b-1">Books to read:</h3>
            <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
                {this.renderList()}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
 } 
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        books: state.books
    };
 }

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ selectBook: selectBook }, dispatch)
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookList);
```

reducer_active_book.js

```
export default function(state = null, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    case 'BOOK_SELECTED':
        return action.payload;
    }
        return state;
}
```

actions.js

```
export function selectBook (book) {
    return {
        type: 'BOOK_SELECTED',
        payload: book
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a github link to your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `classnames` package https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames

`import classNames from 'classnames';`

```
return this.props.books.map((book) => {
        return (
            <li key={book.title} 
                className={classnames({'list-group-item':true, 'active': book.active})} 
                onClick={() => this.props.selectBook(book)}>
                {book.title}
            </li>
        )
    })
```

active class will affect only if book.active is true

//EDIT
you have to pass reducer_active_book property from your state through mapStateToProps

```
function mapStateToProps (state) {
return {
    books: state.books,
    reducer_active_book: state.reducer_active_book,
};
```

}

Now in render you can use this.

```
return this.props.books.map((book) => {
        return (
            <li key={book.title} 
                className={classnames({'list-group-item':true, 'active': this.props.reducer_active_book.id === book.id})} 
                onClick={() => this.props.selectBook(book)}>
                {book.title}
            </li>
        )
    })
```

Comment: But how to change this value after click? I'm trying do it in reducer but doesn't work. Shall I rerender component after every click?

Comment: show me how you are composing your reducers. your composeReducers call. Since you are dispatching the call to BOOK_SELECTED with  payload: book, your state must have reducer_active_book property at some nesting level to be equal to selected Book.

Comment: Updated the answer assuming you are having reducer_active_book is composed at root level of your state.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li key={book.title} 
    className={"list-group-item " + (book.flag ? 'active-class' : 'inactive-class')}
    onClick={() => this.props.selectBook(book)}>
    {book.title}
</li>
```

Try setting a 'flag' when one book is selected, and conditionally add style classes(active-class/inactive-class) accordingly

Comment: But how/where to define `flag`?

Comment: flag to each book object to know if its selected/not, updated whenever selection is toggled

Comment: ok. I've added new value to each of book and set this to false. I'm trying to change this `flag` to `true` (in reducer_active_book file) when element is click but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to access book.flag?

Comment: export default function(state = null, action) {
        switch(action.type) {
        case 'BOOK_SELECTED':
        action.payload.flag = true;
        console.log(action.payload);
            return action.payload
        }
            return state;
    }

Comment: I change value of flag but there is no changes on my view.

Comment: have u defined active-class accordingly?

Comment: yes. When I click of `li` element I see that `flag` is changing to true but element still has `inactive` class.

Answer (score 0):

**In Book List Component**

```
function mapStateToProps(state){

  return {
       books:state.books,
       ActiveBook:state.ActiveBook
  };
}



renderList(){

 console.log(this.props.books);
  return this.props.books.map( (book,idx)=>{

        return <li
         onClick={ ()=>this.props.selectBook(book) }
         className= {"list-group-item  " + ( this.props.ActiveBook ? ( this.props.ActiveBook.title===book.title ? "active" : "") : '') }  key={idx}>{book.title}</li>
   } );
}
```

I have done correctly using this.